# capturing video from webcam and saving to a file

Tags: command-line, video, webcam, ffmpeg, gstreamer

I am trying to capture video(alongwith audio) from a webcam.
I need to record the video and save it to a file,for further processing.
Would like to do it through CLI.

Any ideas how to do it using *ffmpeg* or *gstreamer*.

I am getting these errors:

```
1.gstreamer:-  erroneous pipeline: no element "xvimagesink".  
2.ffmpeg   :-  unable to find suitable output format for video4linux2.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Cheese webcam studio](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Cheese) can record Video and take photo's with effects.

As for cli recording, see if this will work

```
streamer -q -c /dev/video0 -f rgb24 -r 3 -t 00:30:00 -o ~/outfile.avi
```

```
ffmpeg -f oss -i /dev/dsp -f video4linux2 -s 320x240 -i /dev/video0 out.mpg
```

---

**Source**:

- [[ubuntu] how to record the webcam with command line? [Archive]  - Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1337440.html)
- [webcam & microphone command line fun ....](http://forums.opensuse.org/general-chit-chat/415024-webcam-microphone-command-line-fun.html)

Comment: thanks for help,  
but i am using *gstreamer*(gst-launch-0.10) not *streamer*

Comment: @blade19899 It seems that `/dev/dsp` is no more available. It is replaced by `alsa`. see [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/103755/52402)

Comment: Yes, the ffmpeg command results in `/dev/dsp: No such file or directory` on Unbuntu 2015.10. And by the way, the streamer command records in quality much lower than what a correct ffmpeg command produces.