# Webcam video recorder

Tags: software-recommendation, webcam, video-recording

Looking for video recorder applications in Ubuntu that can:

- record videos from webcam.
- can save for example last 15 minutes so I can review that recorded video; I don't want it to record all the time (hard disk will get full); only 15 minutes is enough.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/161940/capturing-video-from-webcam-and-saving-to-a-file

Comment: more ways: https://askubuntu.com/questions/186003/anything-better-than-cheese-for-video-capture

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use vlc (`sudo apt-get install vlc -y`).

1. Open vlc, then press `Ctrl+R`
2. choose [capture device] and select your webcam
3. Press [Convert/Save]
4. Choose where to save the file and hit [start].
5. When you are done press ■

Comment: yes that'a it! but I should choose "Play" :)

Comment: What would "v4l2://" showing as the "source" during that dialog flow in VLC mean?

Comment: @matanster v4l2 is short for video for linux v2, it's basically just an API for accessing video devices in linux

Comment: Is it the only responsible value to keep on that field?

Comment: Is it possible to watch the webcam image as VLC records?

Comment: It works, but quality needs to be configured and how to do so is not super intuitive. My videos look grainy by default, whereas Cheese worked out of the box.

Comment: VLC settings for recording looks very incomprehensible and confusing

Comment: I have two options in the sound device dropdown, none of which produces any sound in the playback or the recording. For me it was always a headache to hack VLC into correctly recording videos.

Answer (score 32):

You may use **Cheese**

It ships with Ubuntu by default.

If you don't see in your installed software list, you may install this from Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: I find cheese much simpler and friendly to operate than super-sophisticated and UX challenged VLC. It is just simple when you are less picky about formats and configurations.

Comment: I agree that Cheese is the simplest to use. I've tried a few others, and no matter what I tried to do, the volume level of the audio playback was too low. Then I tried Cheese, and it just works 'out of the box'.

Comment: Cheese looks great. Unfortunately it crashes when recording a video on my system.

Comment: And for me the recording starts very laggy, and in VLC the time slider jumps immediately to minute 13. Maybe the beginning of the file is corrupted. #justusualshinyandsupereasytouselinuxsoftwarethings

Answer (score 1):

[Webcamoid](https://webcamoid.github.io/) worked for me easily. `sudo apt-get install webcamoid`, click record. (It worked fine with 3gp encapsulating H264, mpeg didn't work.)

I also tried cheese, which couldn't detect my webcam, and VLC, which detected my webcam under "Capture Devices" and sometimes under `/dev/video*`, but which I couldn't get to actually record anything (could be a technical or a UX problem).

Comment: didnt work well for me

Comment: Installed the apt version. As the default mp4/avi codec options didn't work I kept trying to find a working config. Some produced 0 byte files, some crashed Webcamoid, some only recorded video, no sound. Changed to the snap version. No config seemed to work, it produced corrupted files. After this, and trying all other answers, I was concluding Linux is not yet ready to record videos without expert knowledge in 2023. Then accidentally I found a working combo. So thank you!